# store parameters of one macro in another macro

Tags: macros

I want to create a macro that expands to some parameters to provide to another macro. Here is a very simple example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\parameters} { {2} {3} }
  \[
     \frac\parameters % \frac{2}{3}
   \] 

 \end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot. This is a macro expansion language, macro does not expand them self.  In this case `\expandafter\frac\parameters` help. There are methods in LaTeX3 that can expand parameters automatically before use.

Comment: But you can use \newcommand{\twothirds}{\hbox{$\frac{2}{3}$}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\expandafter\frac\parameters
```

The problem is that `\frac` wants two arguments and looks for them *without interpreting tokens* (and discarding white space during such search).

In your case the first argument would be `\parameters` and the second one `\]`, which obviously leads to the very wrong

```
\frac{\parameters}{\]}
```

that is then reduced to the more primitive

```
{\parameters\over\]}
```

Chaos ensues.

Let's implement a new command, namely

```
\newcommand{\FRAC}{\expandafter\frac}
```

so that `\FRAC{2}{3}` and `\FRAC\parameters` would produce the same result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\FRAC}{\expandafter\frac}

\newcommand{\parameters}{{2}{3}}

\begin{document}
\[
\FRAC{2}{3}=\FRAC\parameters
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works because

```
\expandafter\frac\parameters
```

is translated first into `\frac{2}{3}`. On the other hand,

```
\expandafter\frac{2}{3}
```

will try to expand `{`, which isn't expandable.

Comment: Good explication